# Can't get data out of associative array

Tags: php, api, associative-array

I'm using an api to send a request like this:

```
$r = $test->methodName($input);
```

and the response is:

```
Array ( [inputname] => Array ( [id] => 40145579 [name] => InputName [profileIconId] => 605 [Level] => 13 [revisionDate] => 1426878139000 ) )
```

So i looked around on the internet and if I want to print the id or store it in a variable I would have to do it as follow

```
echo $r->id;
```

But the page logs this instead:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   *file location* on line 34

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to PHP

Thanks

Comment: `$r['inputname'][0]['id']` because your array is array not objects.

Comment: Works without the [0], thanks a lot!

Comment: Ahh. Yeah. :D No prob bro. :D

Answer (score 1):

Use Like This 
Array

```
$a= array( 'inputname' => array( 'id' => 40145579 ,'name' => 'InputName', 'profileIconId'=> 605 ,'Level' => 13 ,'revisionDate' => 1426878139000 ));
```

Output

```
echo $a['inputname']['id'];
```